# how to set small icon notification dynamically

Tags: android

I want set small icon notification that received from server. my app download an icon and i want show notification with this icon.

I saw this question but i can't find my answer.

```
File myFile = new File(myPicAddress);
Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentTitle("UPDATE APP")
                .setContentText(myNotificationText)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)//set myFile??
                .setTicker("force android update!")
                .setWhen(triggerTime)
                .build();
```

my app is connected to server and download my icon then i want show notification with my icon downloaded from server.

Comment: So you want to use icons that downloaded after the app installed?

Comment: yes, my app is connected to server and download my icon then i want show notification with my icon downloaded from server.

Answer (score 0):

First download bitmap from url and then set it as icon like below

```
Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL("Your URL");


public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

and then set bitmap to small icon

```
Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentTitle("UPDATE APP")
                .setContentText(myNotificationText)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setSmallIcon(bitmap)//set myFile??
                .setTicker("force android update!")
                .setWhen(triggerTime)
                .build();
```

Updted for API 23 and above use like below

```
notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(Icon.createWithBitmap(yourDownloadedBitmap));
```

Comment: i have an error for "Icon.createWithBitmap".. what is Icon?!

Comment: @mehrdadib it's a inbuilt class for  perform operation related to bitmap .it's must use 23 and above 23 api,more reffer this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Icon.html

Comment: i use lower 23 but setSmallIcon(bitmap) has error in builder can not be applied. how can i use?